# Ticket-Change probability problem

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics

Here is another question from the book of V. Rohatgi and A. Saleh. I would like to ask help again. Here it goes:

Waiting in line for a Saturday morning movie show are $2n$ children. Tickets are priced at a quarter each. Find the probability that nobody will have to wait for change if before a ticket is sold to the first customer, the cashier has $2k$ ($k<n$) quarters. Assume that it is equally likely that each ticket is paid for with a quarter or a half-dollar coin.

I find it hard to understand the phrase "nobody waits for change". I hope someone can help. Thanks.

Comment: If the cashier has run out of quarters when somebody wants to pay with a half-dollar, then that customer has to wait until another customer pays with a quarter so the cashier can give change for the half-dollar.

Comment: Hi @Henry! Thanks, so I think I am starting to make sense with this problem. However, I still cannot form the probabilities involved, as much as I do not know how to begin computing.

Comment: To anyone, will I make sense if I consider a $2n$-tuple $(x_1,...,x_{2n})$ of binary values, where 1 would be case that a customer pays a quarter, -1 if half-a-dollar. Then, starting with $2k$, I take $$2k+\sum_{i=1}^s{x_i},\;for\;each\;s\le2n$$ Then, I would simply count the times the particular sum goes to $0$ before it finishes to $2n$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** Apply the **reflection principle** in a similar way to deal with the general case.

This problem is equivalent to starting at $(0, 2k)$ with steps of $(1,1)$ and $(1, -1)$. Without restriction, there are $2^{2n}$ possible paths.

How many ways are there which do not go below the line $y=0$? That's the number of ways that do not touch the line $y=-1$. Let's count the **complement**, namely the number of lines which touch $y=-1$.

For each such path, using the reflection principle, we reflect the path after the last point of contact with the line $y=-1$. This gives us a path from $(0, 2k)$ which ends with $y \leq -1$. Now show that this is a bijection.

The number of such paths is thus clearly $\sum_{i=0}^j { 2n \choose i}$ for a certain value of $j$ which you should determine.

Let's say we took $a$ up steps and $2n-a$ down steps. Since we started out at $(0,2k)$, we would end up at a y-coordinate of $2k + a - (2n-a) = 2k+2a - 2n$. We want this to be $\leq -1$, and hence $2a \leq 2n - 2k - 1 \Rightarrow a \leq n - k - 1$ (since they are all integers). This is our value of $j$.

Comment: Hi @Calvin! I appreciate your hint. However, I am not familiar with Catalan numbers, mainly because I am simply an undergraduate student. Will it be possible to solve this purely on a "Combinatorics" point of view?

Comment: Yes, read up on Catalan numbers and use the reflection principle. It is a basic technique of relative complement, that a high school student can understand

Comment: Thank you @Calvin! I now understand how to approach the problem. Thanks for the hint. At least it led me to learn something new.

Comment: Although I have to comment, I think Catalan's case only accounts for the time when the number of 'quarter-payers' is the same as the number of 'half-dollar-payers' i.e., each accounts for $n$ of the total $2n$ buyers. I think the problem is a more generalized one. Nevertheless, thanks.

Comment: @math_stat_enthusiast Apply the reflection principle in a similar way. You're now starting at $(k,0)$ instead of $(0,0)$ with steps of $(1,1)$ and $(1, -1)$. How many ways are there which do not go below the line $y=0$? That's the number of ways that do not touch the line $y=-1$.

Comment: Ok. This bombardment of information is starting to freak me out. Anyways, I don't know how to properly explain it but something tells me $j$ should be $2n-2k$. Is this correct?

Comment: @math_stat_enthusiast Close, but not quite. What you are choosing for, is the number of up steps that we can have. Clearly, we can't have $2n$ up steps, since we'd never reach below -1 at that rate. If we have $2n-2k$ up steps, where does that lead us to?

Comment: Let me clarify on this, so I think I begin with $\left(0,2k\right)$, and then count the number of ways I can go by $\left(1,1\right)$ or $\left(1,-1\right)$ until I reach the point $\left(2n,j\right)$ without letting $j=0 \; for \; any\; n\; from\; 0\;to\;2n$, since when $j=0$, somebody has to wait right? So I think the quantity you ask me to look for is $n-k$, because I tried it for some small values. Suppose that I am correct, can you explain to me why? Thanks.

Comment: @math_stat_enthusiast Remember that we applied the reflection principle, and are counting the complement, so we want to end up below -1. In order to do so, if we have $a$ up steps and hence $2n-a$ down steps, we would end up at $2k + a - (2n-a) = 2k + 2a - 2n$. Hence, in order for it to be $\leq -1$, we need $ a \leq n - k - 1 $.

Comment: Ah! Now I get it. Thank you very much! This was after 2 days of thinking. I think I have to review my basic maths a lot. Thanks for the help. It is very much appreciated. @Calvin

Comment: @math_stat_enthusiast Thanks for making the edits. There are minor mistakes in my notation, and I would appreciate if you can correct them. Your edit got rejected likely because people didn't understand check through everything thoroughly. Please make the edit again, and reference this comment so that the reviewers know to approve your edit. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

The probability that the $i$th child will have to wait is zero for $i\le2k$, since the cashier had that many quarters. The chances that the $(2k+1)$th child has to wait are equal to the probability that every single one of the $2k$ children before that one paied with a half-dollar coin. So it is $2^{-2k}$.

Easy so far. But after that it becomes more complicated. So let's try tabulating some numbers, like this:

```
 i|    W   0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13  14
 0:                1
 1:            1       1
 2:        1       2       1
 3:    1       3       3       1
 4:    2   3       6       4       1
 5:    7       9      10       5       1
 6:   14   9      19      15       6       1
 7:   37      28      34      21       7       1
 8:   74  28      62      55      28       8       1
 9:  176      90     117      83      36       9       1
10:  352  90     207     200     119      45      10       1
11:  794     297     407     319     164      55      11       1
12: 1588 297     704     726     483     219      66      12       1
```

This is for $k=1$ and $n=6$, so the cashier starts with two quarters. The row number $i$, starting at zero, indicates how many children have already payed their ticket. The columns indicate how many quarters the cashier has. The entries in the body indicate proportions of probabilities. Each row sums up to $2^i$, so in order to obtain a real probability value, you'd have to divide by $2^i$.

The table starts pretty much like Psacal's triangle. Each cell is the sum of the two cells diagonally above it. One transition represents a quarter paid, the other a quarter returned. But there is that special column denoted `W`. It represents a situation where someone has to wait. There is no leaving that column: if anyone had to wait at any time, no amount of non-waiting will change the fact that someone had to wait. So in that column, the rule is multiply its value by $2$ (to compensate for the change in row sum) and add the value from the column $0$.

The probability that nobody has to wait can be read from the last row of this table using the formula

$$1 - \frac{W_{2n}}{2^{2n}}$$

So if you knew how to compute this $W_i$ sequence (not only for $k=1$ but for arbitrary $k$), then you'd know your answer. But there is no obvious way to compute that `W` column without computing the rest of the table as well. So take the sequence in the `W` column to [OEIS](http://oeis.org/), and you will find [A191389](http://oeis.org/A191389):

> Number of valleys at level $0$ in all dispersed [Dyck paths](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DyckPath.html) of length $n$ (i.e. in all [Motzkin paths](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MotzkinNumber.html) of length $n$ with no $(1,0)$ steps at positive heights)

Links and formatting added by me. OEIS does not know a simple closed formula for these beasts, although it does have a generating function. For $k=2$, the sequence isn't listed in OEIS any more. It starts like this:

```
1,2,9,18,56,112,299,598,1471,2942,6885,13770
```

I suggest you have a closer look at these [Dyck paths](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DyckPath.html) and [Motzkin paths](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MotzkinNumber.html) and see if you can leverage any results made for those to address this issue here. If not, you can always use the table-building rules described above to compute the probability. I doubt that you can avoid recursive definitions, so you might as well use the one underlying that table:

\begin{align*}
t_{0,j} &= \begin{cases}
1 & \text{if } j = 2k \\
0 & \text{else}
\end{cases}
\\
t_{i+1,j} &= \begin{cases}
t_{i,1} & \text{if }j=0 \\
t_{i,j-1} + t_{i,j+1} & \text{else}
\end{cases}
\\
W_i &= \sum_{j=0}^{i-1} 2^j t_{j,0}
\\
p &= 1-\frac{W_{2n}}{2^{2n}}
= 1-\frac{\sum_{i=0}^{2n-1}2^i t_{i,0}}{2^{2n}}
= 1-\sum_{i=0}^{2n-1}2^{i-2n} t_{i,0}
\end{align*}